# How to run Apache Ignite as daemon on Windows

Tags: windows, daemon, ignite

I can run Ignite Node like this on Windows.

```
ignite.bat
```

But This is synchronously-running mode. How can I run Apache Ignite as daemon on Windows?

If I ran node on Linux I could run it using fork but on Windows I do not know how.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Ignite.NET node as a Windows Service:

```
Apache.Ignite.exe /install
```

Ignite.NET is a superset of Ignite, so it will work with Java nodes just fine. The only limitation is the need for explicit BinaryConfiguration: https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/platform-interoperability#mixed-platform-clusters

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service wrapper, like [1] for example.

[1] http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp